# Install pip on window 10 pc

Tags: pip, python-3.10

I am having trouble to install pip on new PC.

I was thinking i may need admin account, so i ran as admin mode.

However, it doesn't help..

I am not sure what can be cause of issue.

I run

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
```

And, it copied get-pip.py file on my pc

And i run

```
py get-pip.py
```

However, it doesn't do anything.
it shows like

> C:\user\myaccount>py get-pip.py
>
> C:\user\myaccount>

it was showing like this

I am not sure what i missed..

If I type  py --version
version was Python 3.10.5.
And I am using windows 10

Comment: You most likely already have pip installed

Answer (score 0):

Run it in command prompt with administrator, worked for me.